# cannot change #![recursion_limit = "256"] in generated schema.rs using diesel print-schema

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to implement a microservice using rust and i'm starting generating the whole model of monolithic application with 400+ tables with 200+ column in some cases.

I generated schema using:

```
diesel print-schema > src/schema.rs
```

and model with diesel_ext

```
`diesel_ext --model > src/models.rs`
```

When i build my code i got the following error:

```
error: recursion limit reached while expanding `__diesel_parse_columns!`
   --> src/schema.rs:22:1
    |
22  | / table! {
23  | |     agreement (id) {
24  | |         id -> Int4,
25  | |         deleted -> Bool,
...   |
267 | |     }
268 | | }
    | |_^
    |
    = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`generatore_offerte`)
    = note: this error originates in the macro `__diesel_parse_columns` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I tried to place `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` in main, lib, models, schema, everywhere but the error is always the same.

Where i need to place this settings to solve this error?

Comment: As an additional note: Diesel only supports tables with up to 128 columns. So you will likely hit problems with a schema with that large tables.

Comment: thanks for the info. i will try to extract the first bounded context / microservice without this kind of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally it worked,

probably there was something else missed too.

It worked when i placed `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` only in my `lib.rs`

[image]